# Verilog -- "and reduction" & duty cycle

Tags: verilog

I am studying this Verilog file:

```
`default_nettype none

module stroboscope(i_clk, o_led);
    
    input wire i_clk;
    output wire o_led;

    reg [19:0] counter;
    initial counter = 0;

    always @(posedge i_clk)
        begin
            counter <= counter + 1'b1;
        end
    
    assign o_led = &counter[19:15];

endmodule
```

I figured out already that if I change the `assign` from it's current state to what is shown, below frequency of blinking LED `o_led` remains constant while it's duty cycle is increased to 100% *(when it is turned on)*:

```
assign o_led = &counter[19:19];
```

[image]

It is possible to decrease the duty cycle now by setitng the same line to:

```
assign o_led = &counter[19:17];
```

[image]

Again... by setitng the same line to:

```
assign o_led = &counter[19:15];
```

[image]

And finally setting the same line as shown below will make a duty cycle of 0%:

```
assign o_led = &counter[19:0];
```

[image]

---

So how does unary `&` operator that represents a *"and reduction"* achieve this in the presented case?

I know a simple example of how this works i.e.

```
&`4b1101 = 0
```

The *"and reduction"* looks like this:

```
1101
 101
  01
   0
```

But, the example is much more complex, and I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
&counter[19:15]
```

is the same as:

```
counter[19] & counter[18] & counter[17] & counter[16] & counter[15]
```

The reduction-AND operator just does a bit-wise AND of each of its bits.  So, your `o_led` signal is only high when all these 5 bits of `counter` are high, as between the cursors in the following diagram (click on the image to enlarge):

[image: waves]

The pulsewidth of `o_led` matches that of the LSB in your reduction-AND expression.  In my code above, the LSB is 15.  If you change the LSB to 16, the pulsewidth doubles.